# After the file notification function is enabled on the DriveKit client, However, the file change notification is not received when the file is deleted

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

After the file notification function is enabled on the DriveKit client, the file change notification is successfully registered. However, the file change notification is not received when the file is deleted.

The server interface is as follows:
[image: The server interface is as follows:]

1. What is the type of file change that will call back the third-party file change notification interface?
2. How Do I Debug the Interface for Notifying Third-Party File Changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The app invokes the [Changes.getStartCursor](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/drivekit-drive-changes#getStartCursor) interface to obtain the cursor value required by [Changes.subscribe](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/drivekit-drive-changes#subscribe). Call the [Changes.subscribe](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/drivekit-drive-changes#subscribe) API to register the file push notification function. This API returns the Channel object after the registration is successful. The developer needs to return the channelToken in the Channel object to the third-party server for subsequent authentication. In addition, the developer can perform subsequent processing such as updating and stopping the push notification based on the Channel object.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/cn/doc/development/HMS-Guides/drivekit-nop-client-development#watchChange

2. Notifications are triggered when the following file status changes:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/cn/doc/development/HMS-Guides/drivekit-nop-server-development#h1-1576503999176